# Visual studio re-installing installed components

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I already have VS c# express installed. And now I want to install VS web express. Why is it trying to install a component that I already have installed (sp1 KB983509)? Is this normal?

Comment: What do you mean? You have a duplicate installation?

Comment: @gideon No. it was telling me during installation that it was installing it, so I quickly cancelled it, not wanting it to interfere with my current installation. But after it stopped installing (which took a while) it informed me that it installed it and that I have to restart.

Comment: My guess is it launched the installation section related to that component, or the installer for the component, which is why it was shown. The component install process will probably check for it already being present and early-exit. I've never had a problem installing multiple VS Express languages, but I haven't tried in a while.

Comment: @peachykeen That's what I thought at first, but it was spending some time "installing" it instead of going on to the next component. Anyway, your answer that you've never had a problem installing multiple languages is enough. I think I'll give it a go. Thanks. (You can post it as an answer so I can accept it.)

Comment: These are separate products with their own install directory.  Re-applying the service pack is normal.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. this seems to be _the_ answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From previous attempts, this does seem normal, although I don't think it actually does the full installation of the component. It shouldn't cause any problems; you definitely can have multiple packs of VS Express.